# Removing kubernetes.io/aws-ebs in-tree StorageClass

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

After installation of `aws-ebs-csi-driver` I've realized that there is default in-tree implementation `kubernetes.io/aws-ebs` which is deprecated according to [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi-migration-faq.html#csi-migration-faq-aws-ebs-provisioner):

```
$ kubectl get StorageClass
NAME            PROVISIONER             RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
ebs-generic     ebs.csi.aws.com         Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   false                  91s
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   false                  7h42m
```

The question is, is it good idea to remove it or at least making newer one as default? 
Will further EKS upgrade bring old `kubernetes.io/aws-ebs` StorageClass again? Is it reasonable at all?

I am using AWS EKS.